# Google Earth Engine: Evapotranspiration Linear Regression MODIS

Tags: google-earth-engine, regression

I am trying to do a Linear Regression about Evapotranspiration using MODIS and I get this error when I try to inspect the value of the pixels in the result layer: ***"Error Array index 1 out of bounds.  Expected value between 0 and -1, found, 0."***

The code is the next:

```js
// Simple regression of year versus NDVI.

// Define the start date and position to get images covering TDPS,
// Bolivia, from 2000-2010.
var start = '2000-01-01';
var end = '2014-12-31';

var region = table2


// Filter to Collection
// time of year to avoid seasonal affects, and for each image create the bands
// we will regress on:
// 1. A 1, so the resulting array has a column of ones to capture the offset.
// 2. Fractional year past 2000-01-01.
// 3. SAVI.
// 4. Mask Clouds
var col = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/NTSG/MOD16A2/105")
  .filterDate(start, end)
  .filterBounds(region)
  .map(function(image) {
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
    var yearOffset = date.difference(ee.Date(start), 'year');
    return ee.Image(1).addBands(yearOffset).toDouble();
  });

print(col)
// Convert to an array. Give the axes names for more readable code.
var array = col.toArray();
var imageAxis = 0;
var bandAxis = 1;

// Slice off the year and ndvi, and solve for the coefficients.
var x = array.arraySlice(bandAxis, 0, 2);
var y = array.arraySlice(bandAxis, 2);
var fit = x.matrixSolve(y).clip(region);

// Get the coefficient for the year, effectively the slope of the long-term
// NDVI trend.
var slope = fit.arrayGet([1, 0]).clip(region);

Map.addLayer(slope);

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: slope,
  description: 'ET_slope_MODIS',
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  region: geometry
});
```

Does anyone know which is the main issue?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that [you should not use arrays when you don't need to](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging#avoid-converting-type-unnecessarily).  If I'm interpreting your intention correctly, here it is the better way:

```js
var start = '2000-01-01';
var end = '2014-12-31';

var col = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/NTSG/MOD16A2/105").select('ET')
  .filterDate(start, end)
  .map(function(image) {
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
    var yearOffset = date.difference(ee.Date(start), 'year');
    return ee.Image(1).addBands(yearOffset).float().addBands(image);
  });

var regression = col.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression(2));

var coeffsImage = regression
    .select('coefficients')
    .arrayProject([0])
    .arrayFlatten([['constant', 'timeCoeff']]);

Map.addLayer(coeffsImage, {bands: 'timeCoeff'}, 'timeCoeff');
```

For more on linear regression, see [this page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_regression).

Comment: Is it possible that GEE takes a distance equidistant for the independent variable (time)? If images are daily will take (day1,day2,day3...) but if there is a gap of 37 days between image3 and image4, does GEE take that gap?